# Woocommerce Checkout does not complete – infinite spinning icon

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having issues on Woo Commerce checkout page where there is infinite spinning icon stays there. Site hosted on Nginx virtual server. Woo commerce version is 3.2.1.

I have searched o forums and people had solved their issues either by increasing php memory or some css tricks.

**Chrome Console shown these errors:**

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)
/?wc-ajax=update_order_review 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments`

**What I have tried to solve:**

- Increased memory to 128M.

  Disabled all other plugins, even disabled and enabled Woo commerce
  plugin too.

  Disabled cache.

  Disabled Nginx redirect force to https.

  Tried using another theme, also tried default simple theme.

  In general settings, everything looks ok.

  Woocommerce status shows no errors.

Still looking for solution..

Any solution/idea?

Comment: Possible mod_security issues with the server.  I've seen 404 errors returned before for the admin-ajax.php call when you look at the Network tab in debug console for XHR.

Comment: 405 not allowed means the HTTP method you tried is not permitted to be used for that URL. Check whether you should be using GET, POST, PUT or DELETE for your ajax call.

Comment: It was working well before Woo Commerce update a week ago. No changes were made on server side.

Comment: "Woo Commerce update a week ago"...and "No changes were made on server side". How did Woo Commerce get updated if no changes were made on the server? That makes no sense. Perhaps WooCommerce's API changed to require a different HTTP method for the URL in question. Check the release notes and/or latest documentation.